# Simple NSInteger and NSMutableArray question

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I'm trying to access an array using another array integer value as an index.

```
 NSInteger index=[appDelegate.randomRiddles objectAtIndex:appDelegate.randomRiddlesCounter];
 int i = index;
 questionText.text = [[appDelegate.currentRiddlesContent objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"question"];

//where appDelegate.randomRiddlesCounter is an NSInteger and appDelegate.randomRiddles is a NSMutableArray
```

However I'm getting incompatible pointer to int conversion warning. How can I fix this above code? The warning I get is coming from the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
NSNumber *index = [appDelegate.randomRiddles objectAtIndex: appDelegate.randomRiddlesCounter];
int i = [index intValue];
questionText.text = [[appDelegate.currentRiddlesContent objectAtIndex: i] objectForKey: @"question"];
```

NSInteger is an integral type, not an object.

Comment: Actually, you beat me, I was about to write the same as an answer. ;)

Comment: @omz: LOL! The competition for reputation is murderous here. <very big grin>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int i = [index intValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

An NSArray like object can only store Objective-C object pointers (i.e. everything that you can assign to an id)

With objectAtIndex you get the object, with indexOfObject:(id)anObject you get the corresponding index.

These two instructions are both valid:

```
id bla = [appDelegate.randomRiddles objectAtIndex:appDelegate.randomRiddlesCounter];
NSInteger index = [appDelegate.randomRiddles indexOfObject:myObject];
```

The second assumes that myObject is at least of type id
So you try to convert a pointer to an int. Therefore the warning is issued.